# Trying to create a separate html page using specific data from another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I am currently in the process of creating a baseball-themed website backed by a database. I have a Scores page that displays a league scoreboard for a chosen date by the user: 
[Screenshot of Scores page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0nG9.jpg)

I am using retrosheet game logs stored in a sqlite database to make this happen with the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, v.teamName AS 'Visitor', h.teamName AS 'Home' "
            . "FROM Games2 "
            . "INNER JOIN TeamNames AS v "
            . "ON Games2.vTeam = v.teamID "
            . "INNER JOIN TeamNames AS h "
            . "ON Games2.homeTeam = h.teamID "
            . "WHERE date = $date";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch(SQLITE3_ASSOC)):
    ?>
    <div class="content">
        <table class="left">
            <tr>
                <th> </th>
                <th>R</th>
                <th>H</th>
                <th>E</th>
                <th rowspan="3"><a href="./BoxScore.php"><input id="box" type="button" value="Box Score"></a></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Visitor']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['visitScore']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['vH']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['vE']; ?></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Home']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['homeScore']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['hH']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['hE']; ?></td>
            </tr>

        </table>   
    </div>
```

Now, where my issue is coming in. I'm trying to have it so when my "Box Score" button is clicked it redirects the user to a unique Box Score page built with the queried data on my Scores page. Could anyone provide some assistance about how I could/should go about doing this?

I was thinking I could store the date and teams in PHP variables and then be able to query again on the new page using those variables to access that specific game possibly?

Comment: Send the needed data as POST data to your next page. On a side note. SqlLite is mostly useful as a local database for example for apps. Not really good for websites in my opinion.

Comment: On the link `./BoxScore.php` append the row id as a GET param, then on that page do the query again for that id.